# Indefinite integral of a rational function with linear denominator: $ \int \frac{ x^7}{(x+1)}{dx} $

Tags: integration, rational-functions

$$ \int \frac{ x^7}{(x+1)}{dx} $$
$$ \int \frac{ \left(x^7 + x^6 - x^6 - x^5 + x^5 + x^4 -x^4 - x^3 + x^3 + x^2 - x^2 -x^1 + x^1 +1 -1\right ) }{\left(x+1\right)}{dx}$$
$$ \int { \left(x^6 -  x^5 + x^4  - x^3  + x^2 -x +1 - \frac{1}{x+1}\right)}{dx}$$

$$\frac{x^7}{7} - \frac{x^6}{6} + \frac{x^5}{5} -\frac{x^4}{4}+ \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^1}{1} -\frac{\log(x+1)}{1}  +C $$
Is there any other good way to do this  ?

Comment: Another probably tougher $x+1=y$

Comment: Along the same lines as yours, $\frac{x^7+1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+1}$, and we can simplify $\frac{x^7+1}{x+1}$.

Comment: Maybe, but your way is really nice, in my opinion the best. +1

Comment: I tried to make the title more searchable. This will help in locating duplicates and related questions.

Comment: My teacher did some Geometric progression stuff and he calculated it easily . But I was not able to catch him what he did .

Comment: @AakashKumar I edited my answer to include what your teacher most likely did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$I=\int\frac{x^7}{x+1}dx$$
Apply $x+1\to y$ to get
$$I=\int\frac{(y-1)^7}{y}dy$$
Using the binomial theorem
$$I=\int\frac{1}{y}\sum_{k=0}^{7}\binom{7}{k}y^k(-1)^{7-k}dy$$
$$=\int\sum_{k=0}^{7}\binom{7}{k}y^{k-1}(-1)^{7-k}dy$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{7}\int\binom{7}{k}y^{k-1}(-1)^{7-k}dy$$
$$=C-\ln|y|+\sum_{k=1}^{7}\frac{1}{k}\binom{7}{k}y^k(-1)^{7-k}$$
$$=C-\ln|x+1|+\sum_{k=1}^{7}\frac{1}{k}\binom{7}{k}(x+1)^k(-1)^{7-k}$$
At which point you have by most standards a satisfactory answer.
**EDIT**
If you teacher did some geometric progression stuff this might have been what he did:
$$I=\int\frac{x^7}{x+1}dx$$
$$=\int\frac{y^7}{1-y}dy\qquad(x\to -y)$$
$$=-\int\frac{-1+1-y^7}{1-y}dy$$
$$=\int\frac{1}{1-y}dy-\int\frac{1-y^7}{1-y}dy$$
$$=\ln|1-y|-\int\left(\sum_{n=0}^6y^n\right)dy$$
$$=\ln|1-y|-\sum_{n=0}^6\int y^ndy$$
$$=\ln|1-y|-\sum_{n=1}^7\frac{y^n}{n}$$
$$=\ln|1+x|-\sum_{n=1}^7\frac{(-x)^n}{n}$$
That method there makes use of the partial sum formula for a geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

Same as your method : But try to use reduction formulas for higher degrees :
**Let**

$$I_n= \int \frac{x^n}{(x+a)}dx$$

$$I_n= \int \frac{(x+a)x^{n-1}-ax^{n-1}}{(x+a)}dx$$

$$I_n= \int x^{n-1}dx-a\int \frac{x^{n-1}}{(x+a)}dx$$

So $$I_n+aI_{n-1}=\frac{x^n}{n}$$

Now you have to find $I_7$

Comment: i think your approach is almost the same as questioner's

Comment: yes ! But I have shown him how to use reduction formulas to evaluate for higher degrees !

Comment: In general $I_n=(-a)^n\ln|x+a|+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-a)^{n-k}x^k}{k}$